# GHPython Von Koch function ERROR on Grasshopper

Tags: python, grasshopper, rhino3d

First time I use Python Script on Grasshopper. I can’t find where are my mistakes. I am almost at the end but now I have this Error message. Can anyone help me to find the mistake?

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs

def koch(v1,v2) :

    dist=rs.Distance(v1,v2) 

    p1=v2-v1
    p1=rs.VectorUnitize(p1)
    p1*=dist*dist1
    p1+=v1

    p2=v2-v1

    cross=v2-v1
    cross=rs.VectorUnitize(cross)
    cross=rs.VectorRotate(cross, 90, (0,0,1))
    cross*=dist*dist4

    p2=rs.VectorUnitize(p2)
    p2*=dist*dist2
    p2+=v1+cross

    p3=v2-v1
    p3=rs.VectorUnitize(p3)
    p3*=dist*dist3
    p3+=v1

    return (v1,p1,p2,p3,v2)

def recursive(v1,v2,gens, lineList):

    if(gens>0):

        newPts = koch(v1,v2)
        l = rs.AddPolyline([newPts(0),newPts(1),newPts(2),newPts(3),newPts(4)])
        lineList.append(l)

        recursive(v1,newPts(0),gens-1)

    return lineList

allLines=()

a=recursive(pt1,pt2,2,allLines)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcXQT.png)

Comment: could you add the error you get ? and you are using some variables that seem to be not defined in your sample (`dist1`,`dist4`...)

Answer (score 0):

Your line `l = rs.AddPolyline([newPts(0), newPts(1), newPts(2), newPts(3), newPts(4)])` is incorrect.

Accessing an item in a tuple requires **square** brackets. Replace with the following line:

```
l = rs.AddPolyline([newPts[0], newPts[1], newPts[2], newPts[3], newPts[4]])
```